# How to allocate an enter key based event to a selected <li> element within <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, enter

I have the following `<ul>` unordered list element:

```
<ul id="here"></ul>
```

which by default has following css code:

```
#here{
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: white;
    width:175px;
    height:300px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display:none;   
    padding:0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

#here li:hover,
#here li.--focus {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am populating this `<ul>` element with `<li>` elements dynamically which are product names being taken from a database using JQuery .ajax(). The `<ul>` element comes to view only when it is being populated. Otherwise it display is `none`. And I can also navigate among the `<li>` elements using up or down key.

The code for populating the `<ul>` element is:

```
var pr= ["Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4", "Product5", "Product6"];
for (var option in pr) {
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  newLi.innerHTML=pr[option];
  $("#here").append(newLi);
}
```

And the code for navigating among the `<li>` elements is:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var children = $("#here").children();
    if (currentFocus === undefined) {
      currentFocus = 0;
    } else {
      currentFocus += e.keyCode === 38 ? -1 : 1;
      currentFocus < 0 && (currentFocus = children.length - 1);
      currentFocus >= children.length && (currentFocus = 0);
    }
    children.removeClass("--focus");
    children.eq(currentFocus).addClass("--focus"); 
  }

});
```

I want to attach an event on the selected `<li>` element and executing a function with the value of `<li>` element upon the pressing of the button enter on keyboard if the `<ul>` element is visible.

i tried the following function but it does not work:

```
$("#here").on("keypress", function(e) { alert("some key pressed");})
```

so, if #here is not registering any function execution on any keypress how can I get it to recognize anything else?

Can anyone guide me how can I do this?

**[Demo for above code](https://jsfiddle.net/nhdabq4x/)**

Comment: selected <li>, does that means clicking on that <li> ?

Comment: @Vivek Doshi 

no  I meant that the <li> element which has the .class --focus, meaning after navigating up or down the <li> element which is under observation and I want to execute a function on pressing keyboard enter key with the value of that specific <li> element.

Comment: I think the keycode of enter is 13

Comment: The keycode for enter key is 13, but the problem is that I cannot get to select that specific <li> element on which to apply this enter key function to. Any idea how can I select that specific <li> element and perform a function on it when enter key is pressed?

Comment: i tried the following function but it does not work:
`$("#here").on("keypress", function(e) {
alert("some key pressed");})`

so if #here is not registering any function execution on any keypress how can I get it to recognize anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with your example: Sorry I used jQuery, I'm in a rush. But simply, find the li that has the class --focus when the enter button is hit. Then get the contents of that list item and do something with them

https://jsfiddle.net/nhdabq4x/

```
// When ENTER is pressed
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // For each li, 
  $('li').each(function() {
    // Check it if has class "--focus"
    if($(this).hasClass('--focus')) {
      // If it does, do something with it!
      $('.product-chosen').text($(this).text())
    };
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bit more jQuery. Might not solve your issue with 'keypress'. Try using the 'keydown' event instead, and test it on some other elements to rule out potential problems with the `ul` element.

```
// Add the function to the 'ul'
$('#here').on('kedown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) {
        e.preventDefault();

    var focused = $('#here .--focus');
    if( focused === undefined )  // no earlier selection, select first
        $('#here li:first').addClass('--focus');


    if( e.keyCode === 38 ) {  // up arrow
        // toggle focus class for selected element and the element above
        var previous = $(focused).prev();
        focused.toggleClass('--focus');
        previous.toggleClass('--focus');
    } else if( e.keyCode === 40 ) { // down arrow
        // toggle focus class for selected element and the element below
        var next = $(focused).next();
        focused.toggleClass('--focus');
        next.toggleClass('--focus');
    }
    // consider adding an else clause that prints a debug message to test this function
}
```